# How many instances of servlet are created by container after loading it? Singleton?

Tags: java, servlets

How many instances of a servlet are created by the servlet container after loading it?
is it only one?

Answer (score 9):

Servlets do **not** adhere to the [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). Servlet classes have a public constructor which already violate the singleton pattern. The creation of servlets is by default just the [Just Create One pattern](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.SingletonVsJustCreateOne). Technically, the container can create as many of them as it needs. Especially if the servlet happens to implement the (deprecated) [`SingleThreadedModel`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/SingleThreadModel.html) interface so that the container can create a pool of those servlet instances in order to improve performance.

However, it is true that the same instance can be shared among multiple requests. That's why it's very important to **not** assign any request/session scoped data as an instance variable of the servlet. It would be shared among multiple requests.

Servlets at its own adheres to the [Template Method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) by the way. This is not related to creation, it is just a behavioral pattern.

#### See also:

- [How do servlets work? Instantiation, sessions, shared variables and multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452)

Comment: Thank you  BalusC for comprehensive reply .By the way I am regular visitor to u r JSF blog :)  !

Answer (score 4):

Only one singleton servlet instance is created per whole application (lazily by default), so it must be thread-safe (watch out for servlet fields). However request and response objects are created per request and thus are thread-safe.

On the other hand, `HTTPSession` is one per user session (duh...), so if the same user accesses the application with two simultaneous requests, consider synchronizing on session. As you can see, servlet threading model is a bit complicated...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, one instances with multiple threads.

Comment: does it use singleton design pattern ?

Comment: I wouldn't expect that the servlet spec specifies that. Are you interested in how a particular implementation handles this? (Tomcat, Jetty, JBoss?)

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. If the answer given by @BalusC is not helpful enough, perhaps you should ask a new question.